# Autofac DI not working on an API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a hard time with this one. My setup works with a normal MVC controller, but not with an API controller. Not sure what I'm doing wrong either.

Here is my container setup.

```
IContainer Container = null;
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType().BaseType.Assembly).PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerRequest().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType().BaseType.Assembly).PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerRequest().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterModule<LoggerModule>();

builder.Register(c =>
{
    // if we don't have owin context ready then just create a new one
    if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null)
    {
        return UserManager.Create(new IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager>(), (System.Data.Entity.DbContext)null);
    }

    return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<UserManager>();
 }).As<IUserManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

 Container = builder.Build();
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(Container);
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));
```

So now I have my basic controllers

```
[Authorize]
public TasksController : ApiController
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public IUserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    public string Get()
    {     
        //logger works, but the usermanager is null
        this.Logger.Info("Entering Get");       
        return this.UserManager.CurrentUser.Name;
    }
}

[Authorize]
public UserController : Controller
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public IUserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {     
        //logger works, AND the usermanager is set too.
        this.Logger.Info("Entering Index");       
        return this.View(this.UserManager.CurrentUser);
    }
}
```

So the weird part is that the MVC controller works fine. I have both a `ILogger` and `IUserManager` instance. But in my Api controller I only have an `ILogger` instance. The `IUserManager` is null.

If I wanted to I can do this within the Api controller to get an instance.

```
((Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver)System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current).RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserManager>();
```

I've also been able to set the IUserManager property by using a custom module (I tested this out in my existing `LoggerModule`), but I want to understand why it won't work by just registering the type. I don't want to keep treating symptoms without fully understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does your MVC controller have a constructor?

Comment: @DavidG No, just the default parameterless constructor

Comment: Never mind, didn't notice you were doing PropertiesAutowired! Anyway, are the ApiControllers in the same assembly as your MVC controllers?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, the MVC and API controllers are both in the same assembly, however, the code to configure Autofac is in a separate assembly. My Autofac configuration code also runs using `WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod`